# scss error "media query expected" - use multiple media queries - standardize the sizes of devices

Tags: node.js, angular, sass

I'm trying to standardize the sizes of the devices on my scss, based on [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp):

```
/** Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
$extra-small-evices: "screen and (max-width: 600px)",
/** Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 601px to 768px) */
$small-devices = 'screen and (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 768px)',
/** Medium devices (landscape tablets, 769px to 991px) */
$medium-devices = 'screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 991px)',
/** Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px to 1200px) */
$large-devices = 'screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1200px)',
/** Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1201px and up) */
$extra-large-devices = 'screen and (min-width: 1201px)'
```

After this, less say that I want to create a media query which the target is the small devices and medium devices:

```
@media $small-devices,
@media $medium-devices{
   ....
}
```

But I'm getting the following error on the  `@media $small-devices,` line:

> [scss] media query expected

Environment: Visual studio code, nodejs, angular 6, gulp,

Any one knows how no solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should tell SASS that your string is meant to be unquoted and treated like regular CSS:

```
@media #{unquote($small-devices)}{
    // Your output here
}
```

You can still use multiple like this:

```
@media #{unquote($small-devices)},
       #{unquote($extra-small-devices)}{
    // Your output here
}
```

But maybe, for style and elegance, you might want to consider building a mixin that just takes all the strings and then build the media query as such:

```
@mixin media( $selectors... ){

    $selector: '';

    @each $s in $selectors {

        @if $selector == '' { $selector: $s; }
        @else { $selector: $selector + ', ' + $s; }

    }

    @media #{unquote($selector)}{

        @content;

    }

}
```

And then use it as such:

```
@include media( $extra-small-devices, $extra-large-devices ){

    ...

}
```

And the output will be:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px), screen and (min-width: 1201px) {

    ...

}
```

Comment: Thank you but it only solves one problem. If I join two media queries to the same code like this: `@media #{unquote($small-devices)}, @media #{unquote($small-devices)} {}`,  I receive the same error but for the second media query

Comment: @RicardoRocha Drop the second `@media`, I just tested this: `@media #{unquote($extra-small-evices)}, #{unquote($extra-large-devices)} {}` and it works. Als, `extra-small` is missing the `d` for `devices`.